# how to link a group of check box tags to a corresponding group of <select> tags

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have the following 3 checkbox tags where each represents a category.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="catpref[]" value=1> Politics<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="catpref[]" value=2> Sports<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="catpref[]" value=3> Economics<br>
```

I need to add next to each category another `<select>` tag of countries that will return the country selected for the corresponding category.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="catpref[]" value=1> Politics
<select class="countrySrch"  name="countbox" id="countbox">@include('includes.country')</select>
<input type="checkbox" name="catpref[]" value=2> Sports
<select class="countrySrch"  name="countbox" id="countbox">@include('includes.country')</select>
<input type="checkbox" name="catpref[]" value=3> Economics
<select class="countrySrch"  name="countbox" id="countbox">@include('includes.country')</select>
```

If I submit the above, there is no link between each catpref[] and it's corresponding country `<select>`. How can this be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your input names with specific keys like this:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="catpref[1]" value="true"> Politics
<select class="countrySrch"  name="catprefspec[1]">@include('includes.country')</select>

<input type="checkbox" name="catpref[2]" value="true"> Sports
<select class="countrySrch"  name="catprefspec[2]">@include('includes.country')</select>

<input type="checkbox" name="catpref[3]" value="true"> Economics
<select class="countrySrch"  name="catprefspec[3]">@include('includes.country')</select>
```

Then you should get 2 arrays `catpref` and `catprefspec` in your request. And they now have keys that matches each other.

P.S. [id attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute) should be unique in the document. Using `id="countbox"` multiple times might result in unexpected errors. You should probably use [class attriubte](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#classes) instead.